# Change variable in CMD

Tags: for-loop, cmd, command-prompt

When I run the for-loop under, it produces a file name like:

test1.pdf.svg

Is there a way to trim/remove this down to produce a file name like:

test1.svg

```
for %%f in (Convert_folder\*.pdf) do (
   REM pdf2svg <input.pdf> <output.svg> 
   "pdf2svg"  %%f "%%f.svg"
)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the filename without the extension using the `~n` modifier against a variable containing a filename.
Have a look [here](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html) for the parameters expansion's options

```
for %%f in (Convert_folder\*.pdf) do (
   REM pdf2svg <input.pdf> <output.svg> 
   "pdf2svg"  %%f "%%~nf.svg"
)
```